# Kак найти самое повторяющееся число в таблице sql?

Tags: sql

Есть столбец таблицы с целыми числами, нужно найти число, которое больше всего повторяется с помощью запроса sql.
Мне кажется, что должна быть какая-то функция, которая это считает, однако я ее не нашел, или сделать это через COUNT() но оно не работает.

Comment: Опишите что вы пробовали и что именно не получается в задаче

Comment: `select count(*) group by ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Допустим и нас такая таблица:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  value INT,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
INSERT INTO test (value) VALUES 
(10),
(20),(20),
(30),(30),(30),
(40);
```

Вначале нам нужно посчитать число повторений для каждого числа. Для это мы используем COUNT(*) и группируем по числу.

```
select 
  value,
  count(*)  as count
  from test
  group by value;
```

Получаем:

| value | count |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | 1 |
| 20 | 2 |
| 30 | 3 |
| 40 | 1 |

---

Добавляем сортировку по убыванию count:

```
select 
 value,
 count(*)  as count
 from test
 group by value
 order by count desc;
```

Получаем:

| value | count |
| --- | --- |
| 30 | 3 |
| 20 | 2 |
| 40 | 1 |
| 10 | 1 |

---

И берем только 1 строку - добавляем LIMIT:

```
select 
 value,
 count(*)  as count
 from test
 group by value
 order by count desc
 limit 1;
```

Получаем:

| value | count |
| --- | --- |
| 30 | 3 |

---

Если же нужно получить только число без количества его повторений - оборачиваем  еще в один select:

```
select value from (
select 
 value,
 count(*)  as count
 from test
 group by value
 order by count desc
 limit 1
) as data;
```

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mh6qwfN3iFgbB9eAvPSqSP/1)

Answer (score -2):

```
select EmployeeId, COUNT(*) as 'Number of orders' from Tasks
group by EmployeeId
having count(*) = (select max(EmployeeId) from Tasks)
```

EmpoyeeId - той самий стовпець з інтовими значеннями